# Shortcuts screen in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this silly issue with vscode.

When selecting a folder or nothing I use to have a screen like this:

[image]

But now I have one just like this, without shortcuts:

[image]

I've looked everywhere in the preferences but can't figure out what I may have touched or changed.
I know it's a stupid question, but it's driving me crazy.

Thanks

Comment: Check the `Workbench > Startup Editor` setting.  Looks like you want `none`.

Comment: No unfortunately is not working...